# Adding pictures taken by a mobile device to a WFS layer in QField

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, wfs, qfield

I have installed QField (2.7.6) on an Android mobile device. The QGIS project on the device is only using some WFS endpoints.

Those endpoints are served by a remote QGIS server installation which is fed by a PostGIS database.

[image]

In the QGIS project used by QField, how could I add picture(s) taken by the mobile device into the PostGIS database*, e.g. using [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (or to a given location on the file system of the server, but in that case, to store the absolute path of the uploaded pictures in the database)?

I've read through [this page](https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/pictures) but this solution seems (I'm not 100% sure) to depict a situation where the QGIS project on the mobile device is having a *direct* connection to a database or to an on-device embedded shapefile.

---

* to this end, in order to not overload the bandwidth, it could be necessary to have some options to set the max height/width (in pixels) and/or size (in bytes) of the image.

Comment: Would think that you'd need to go with storing an HTTP URL to the location of the image on the server, rather than trying to use a file path location.  I understand the reasoning for Base64, but just wondering whether you have  tried providing an image in that format through WFS.